# Changes not reflecting on browser after deploying code on heroku node js app

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-nodejs

I have an app on Heroku. According to the Heroku App deploy guide I followed the below steps to modify the master.
Steps to make the push on Heroku

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push Heroku master
```

The build of deploy was successful but the changes didn't reflect on the browser. I used hard refresh multiple times but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If your app requires a build step to compress and combine assets and you are not seeing recent changes, then it's likely that you are forgetting to run that build step.

If you are using package such as parcel-bundler. you should run it before you deploy it. That would solve the issue.

You can read more on how to run it automatically whenever you deploy your app from here.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#hook-things-up

Comment: Please ask questions instead of answering with a lot of "if this or that". https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer